# Does GC Profiling work?

Tags: profiling, d

If I compile this program like this `dmd -profile=gc test.d` and run it :-

```
import std.stdio;

void add(ref int[] data)
{
    data ~= 1;
    data ~= 2;
}

void main()
{
    int[] a;
    a.reserve(1000);
    a.add();
    writeln(a);
}
```

Then I get a profilegc.log like this :-

```
bytes allocated, allocations, type, function, file:line
              4               1 int[] test.add test.d:5
              4               1 int[] test.add test.d:6
```

I would expect that the `reserve` call would allocate GC memory and the lines 5 and 6 would not allocate any memory because memory is already reserved in the array.

So either :-

1. My understanding of .reserve is wrong.
2. The profiler is giving an incorrect result.
3. There is a problem with reserve

Is one or more of these true? (I want to be able to do a reserve to guarantee that allocations only happen at times I want them to and the profiler doesn't reassure me that this works...)

Comment: I think reserve just checks if enough space is available behind the array to extend it, and moves it if something is in the way. It does not allocate any memory. If you actually want to allocate memory, use `.length = 1000`, but then you need something to keep track of valid members.